Trigger server action from select component
I have a server component and I want to submit my select element value to a server action.
is it possible to do that in following setup(not working) or do I need a client component for this? thanks
import { getCategories } from "@/db/queries";
import { Select } from "flowbite-react";
import { filter } from "@/actions/filter";

export async function CategoryFilter() {
  const categories = await getCategories();

  return (
    <form action={filter}>
      <Select id="category" name="category">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        {categories.map((category: string) => (
          <option key={category} value={category}>
            {category}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </form>
  );
}


Found a alternative way of doing it using a client component
"use client";

import { Select } from "flowbite-react";
import { filter } from "@/actions/filter";
import { getCategories } from "@/db/queries";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function CategoryFilter() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const getAllCategories = async () => {
    const categories = await getCategories();
    setCategories(categories);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCategories();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form action={filter}>
      <Select
        id="category"
        name="category"
        onChange={(e) => e.target.form?.requestSubmit()}
      >
        <option value="all">All</option>
        {categories.map((category: string) => (
          <option key={category} value={category}>
            {category}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </form>
  );
}

